# Docker Networking services unable to connect to each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have this docker compose file shown file

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend-flask:
    build: ./backend   

  frontend-fligh:
    build: ./frontend-fligh
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend-flask
```

In my frontend I'm trying to make a backend api call by doing

```
const response = await fetch('http://backend-flask:5000/search', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(query)
                });
```

but this requests returns me this error
POST http://backend-flask:5000/search net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

in my app.py of my backend flask application the route is defined as well

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) #for production change to have only my site


@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
//more code
```

also note that this works if i change it from backend-flask to localhost:5000/search

i inspected the network and the containers are all in the same network, I'm really lost here, and not sure why it's not working

```
jasonwang@Jasons-MacBook-Pro startUp % docker network inspect startup_default
[
    {
        "Name": "startup_default",
        "Id": "f9507df9f26968c4665da09bf90b24904267b177476c3654197d4b9afbf1dd78",
        "Created": "2023-08-25T02:26:45.523880875Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "1278a785f11c2227638d12aba3c5286a29346134801b43481fcedc5d15037b12": {
                "Name": "startup-redis-1",
                "EndpointID": "cfaf2be033ce04fd9f7cdd5cba4d287d0d3a9ee77edd79324fe8b6dfd2a93ca6",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "5ca87c376d0342d67e07a2452f2ae188af710c65753894fdddda99bb05e0e902": {
                "Name": "startup-backend-flask-1",
                "EndpointID": "24bd57249b98e595b54846d5581655798730b3eb475624fe057599ad1f492b5c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "6a968c8e2bad884cc56540cc43699dc51c479486693e60209add3e890e84d94c": {
                "Name": "startup-frontend-fligh-1",
                "EndpointID": "36598650abb0c25cde0da3442f587771a947f1c8b119f5455834b0d699fa82e1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "startup",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.20.2"
        }
    }
]
```

docker ps shown below

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
fa9c94681ab1   startup-frontend-fligh   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 minutes ago      Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   startup-frontend-fligh-1
66759928be0a   startup-backend-flask    "flask run"              48 minutes ago      Up 5 seconds                            startup-backend-flask-1
1278a785f11c   redis:alpine             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up 5 seconds   6379/tcp                 startup-redis-1
```

THis is the docker file for my backend

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_ENV=development
ENV FLASK_DEBUG=1
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Comment: Can you share the output of [`docker compose ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_ps/) command?

Comment: It's barely unreadable. Add that to the description of the post.

Comment: please show the dockerfile you wrote for your backend

Comment: @Saleh updated with backend dockerfile

Comment: Your frontend application is running in the browser, even if its code is being served from a container.  The browser is outside the Docker environment, so it can't use the Docker-internal DNS names or other Docker networking features.  In development you need to connect to `localhost` and the published `ports:` of the other container, or proxy the backend from your frontend service.

Answer (score 0):

According to the output of `docker compose ps` command, your backend is listening on port `5000` which you have forwarded on port `8000` to the host. So you have to use either `http://backend-flask:5000` or `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: I just updated my docker ps, my docker compse doesnt expose the port for the backend

Comment: also tried changing it with the old method, and changed to :8000, still doesnt' work

Comment: Now your backend doesn't listen on any port. Look at the `startup-redis-1` container, see there's `6379/tcp`? That means that container will accept TCP connections on port `6379`, but it's not forwarded to the host (unlike `startup-frontend-fligh-1`).

Comment: I am showing my dockerfile for my backend redis too, because I'm only making API calls. to the backend from my frontend, I thought I didn't need to expose the port

Comment: Your app needs to be opened on a port in order for the other services to communicate with it. Forwarding it to the host is optional, especially in the case you don't need to access it directly from the host.

Answer (score -2):

It is not a real solution but could you try with this docker-compose to check if it is just the DNS problem?

```
version: '3'
    
services:
  backend-flask:
    build: ./backend  
  test-net:
      ipv4_address: 172.19.33.10


  frontend-fligh:
    build: ./frontend-fligh
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend-flask
    test-net:
      ipv4_address: 172.19.33.11
networks:
  test-net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.19.33.0/24
```

And change this too:

```
const response = await fetch('http://172.19.33.10:5000/search', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(query)
                });
```

Comment: You almost never need to set the container-internal IP addresses.  They're usually not reachable from outside of Docker at all; for example, a browser `fetch()` call can't reach them on most host OS setups.  Docker can assign its own internal IP addresses and you do not need to know or set them yourself.

Comment: yea, any ideas as to the error @DavidMaze